# Loop through varied number of matrices using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Here is the functionality demonstrated on a fixed number of matrices:

```
x = np.matrix('0.5')
y = np.matrix('0.5 0.5; 0.5 0.5')
z = np.matrix('0.75 0.25; 0.34 0.66')
output = []

for i in x.flat:
    for j in y.flat:
        for k in z.flat:
            output.append(i * j * k)
```

I need help solving this issue on a variable number of matrices.  I have tried  using

```
reduce(np.dot, arr)
```

But this is not what I want to do.

Comment: So, the output would be a flattened matrix/array?

Comment: Yes, the output is `[(x[0]*y[0]*z[0])...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `A` holding the list of input matrices, we could just iteratively use `np.outer`. `np.outer` would flatten the inputs on its own, so, we don't need to do it ourselves and only a final flattening step would be needed.

Thus, solution would be -

```
A = [x,y,z,w]
out = A[0]
for i in A[1:]:
    out = np.outer(out, i)
out = out.ravel()
```

Note that the output would be an array. If needed as a matrix, simply wrap it with `np.matrix()` at the end.

Sample run for `4` matrices -

```
In [38]: x = np.matrix('0.5')
    ...: y = np.matrix('0.15 0.25; 0.35 0.45')
    ...: z = np.matrix('0.75 0.25; 0.34 0.66')
    ...: w = np.matrix('0.45 0.15; 0.8 0.2')
    ...: 
    ...: output = []
    ...: for i in x.flat:
    ...:     for j in y.flat:
    ...:         for k in z.flat:
    ...:             for l in w.flat:
    ...:                 output.append(i * j * k * l)
    ...:                 

In [64]: A = [x,y,z,w]
    ...: out = A[0]
    ...: for i in A[1:]:
    ...:     out = np.outer(out, i)
    ...: out = out.ravel()
    ...: 

In [65]: np.allclose(output, out)
Out[65]: True
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.  `ravel()` is what is flattening after each iteration?